# Set font size of substring of content control tag text

Tags: office365, office-js

The text of my content control tag is ABCDEFGH.
I wanted to set font size of 'ABCD' to 10 and of 'EFGH' to 1 .
Is there a way to do so ?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! you can increase the fonts

Comment: Can you explain how ? I want half text with diff font size inside one content control tag.Can you share the code snippet to do so?

Comment: Could you provide some additional detail? What APIs are you using? What Office host are you using (Word, Excel, PowerPoint, Outlook, OneNote)?

Comment: Word office js api ,angular  js

Comment: @MarcLaFleur-MSFT